# bootstrap navbar expandable vertically

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make a bootstrap navbar fixed on top (which i already done) and make it expandable vertically .

I want to put a google maps and all my controls in this navbar fixed on top and make it expandable  vertically so the user can change its size in a responsive way.

My code for the navbar and the google maps div:

```
         <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="col-lg-8">
            <div class="row">
                <div id="map_canvas"></div>               
            </div>

        </div>
```

Edit : I added a jsfiddle, i couldnt add a google maps because of the api key so i put an image instead its the same basically

https://jsfiddle.net/ajzp3vsf/1/

so the image is fixed on top in the navbar what i want to do is to make the navbar expandable vertically a bit like the text field here in stackoverflow.

Comment: Can you please make a working fiddle, that we can understand what is the problem?

Comment: @MiomirDancevic i have tried to explain more and added a jsfiddle

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like this, also you must add your responsive classes to map, this is fiddle with picture

https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/18151/

```
<div class="container">
      <!-- Static navbar -->
      <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
          </div>
          <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li>
                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/1/" />        
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
        </div><!--/.container-fluid -->
      </nav>
</div> <!-- /container -->
```